# Numbers that contain a 1

Tags: c++, algorithm

How can i find qt. numbers includes a 1 in the segment [1..n]? 
eg: for n=29 it is 12; for n=100 it is 20.
n can reach 10^9 and time limit is 2 sec.
language C++

Comment: How are we supposed to write the code for you if you don't tell us what language you're using?

Comment: Question created with 'homework' tag. at least user is honest.

Comment: If you've been asked to solve the question like "how many numbers have a 1 in them", the answer is 100% (once you get to infinity). Likewise for all other digits.

Answer (score 12):

A simple way to check if a single number is to compute its modulo 10: if it's 1 then it does, otherwise divide it by 10 and repeat. If the number is 0, it doesn't include 1.

That should be enough for you to start.

Answer (score 4):

Clever thing to do is create a formula, prove it by recursion, then apply it.

Actually I will not use recursion at first but some simple maths: sort of probability/combinatorial theory although there are no random events here.

Given a number of digits say two, the number of numbers below that do not have any 1s is always going to be 9 to the power of the number of digits, thus for 00 to 99 the are 81 such numbers. Thus there are 19 that do (100-81).

In each case we will count the number of numbers that do not contain any ones.

5394 for example is the sum of the range 0 to 4999 and the sum of the range 5000 to 5394.

Sum to 4999 is the product of the digits: 4*9*9*9 (0-4, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9 excluding 1 in each case)

Sum 5000 to 5394 is the same as the sum from 000 to 394: split 000 to 299, 300 to 394. Thus 2*9*9 + run from 00 to 94 which is 8*9 plus 90-94 which is 4 more.

So from 0 to 5394 there are 4*9*9*9 (2916) + 2*9*9 (162) + 8*9 (72) + 4 = 3154

Subtract from our main number+1 (5395) and we get the solution of 2241. (We subtract from 5395 because we counted from 0 to 5394, which is 5395 numbers)

Solution is take each digit that is >1, subtract one, and multiply by 9 for each digit that appears after it. If the number is 1 we do not subtract one. If the number is zero we skip.

If we encounter a 1 we skip all the remaining digits. Thus if our number is 52136, after reaching the 1 we skip all the rest. (We will have the count up to 52099 and there are no more after that). We still use the whole number for the subtraction at the end.

**For the last digit:** If there have been no 1 digits so far we add the last digit in, and add 1 if it is 0. Thus add 4 for 5394, 1 for 5390, nothing for 5216 because it contains a 1 before the last digit but still add 1 for 5391 (representing 5390 that wasn't include in the earlier count).

Then subtract this sum from our number+1 and subtract 1 more (because I have ranged 0 to N which is N+1 numbers)

n=29 is thus 1*9 + 9 = 18. Subtract from n+1 and we get 12 like you wanted.

n=100: 1*9*9 = 81. Subtract from 101 (our number contains a 1) to get 20.

There is your formula. Now go and program it.

** Slightly alternative way **

In a "recursive" way: We calculate the number of numbers that do not contain a 1 strictly less than our value (not including it) let's call this a name, f(N)

f(10N) is always f(N) * 9. We can prove this easily: there are f(N) numbers that are less than N then multiply these by 10 and add in each of the digits 0 and 2-9 at the end, 9 different digits.

f(10N+m) where 0<=m<=9 is a single digit uses the "last digit add" formula so if N contains a 1 digit it is just f(N) * 9 otherwise add 0 for m=0 1 for m=1 and m-1 for any other.

f(394858) = 7 + 9*f(39485) 
f(573940) = 9*f(57394)
f(491029) = 9*f(49102) (contains a 1 digit)

Your "f" function can recurse and must contain 2 pieces of information: whether it contains a 1 digit and the return value. The base case is single digit

f(N) is the number of numbers strictly less than N that do not contain a 1. To get the number that do, subtract this from N, and add 1 if our number itself contains a 1.

f(10N+M) = 9*f(N) if N contains a 1, 9*f(N)+f(M) if N does not contain a 1.

f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(M) for 2 to 9 is M-1
f(10) = 9 * f(1) = 9
f(100) = 9 * f(10) = 81
solution is 100 - 81 + 1 (because 100 contains a 1 we add one) which gives us 20
f(9) = 8
f(99) = 8*9 + 8 = 80
subtract 80 from 99 to give us 19 and do not add 1 as 99 does not contain a 1.
Now let's try coding:

```
struct res 
{
  unsigned int numDigs;
  bool hasOneDig;

  res( unsigned int n, bool h ) : numDigs( n ), hasOneDig( h ) {}
};

res oneDigitCount( unsigned int input )
{
   assert( input < 10 );

   switch( input )
   {
      case 0: 
         return res( 0, false );
      case 1:
         return res( 1, true );
      default:
         return res( input-1, false );
   }
};

res countNoOnes( unsigned int input )
{
   if( input < 10 )
        return oneDigitCount( input ); // base case that ends recursion

   unsigned int quotient = input / 10;
   unsigned int remainder = input % 10;

   res result = countNoOnes( quotient ); // recursive
   result.numDigs *= 9;

   if( !result.hasOneDig )
   {
       res remainderRes = oneDigitCount( remainder );
       result.numDigs += remainderRes.numDigs;
       if( remainderRes.hasOneDig ) // or remainder==1
          result.hasOneDig = true;
   }

   return result;
}

unsigned int countNumsContainingOne( unsigned int input )
{
   res noOnes = countNoOnes(input);
   unsigned int result = input - noOnes.numDigs;
   if(noOnes.hasOneDig)
     ++result; // as this number has a one

   return result;
}
```

Not very OO, could easily be adapted for C (replace constructor with function that returns the struct) but should work.

Comment: I'm not sure that formula there.

Comment: What about n=16 for example? 1*9+6=15. 17-15=2. (1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

Comment: @user577395 no, it would be 17 - 1*9 = 8.

Comment: Why are you not plus 6? Or n=101: 9*9*1+0*9*9+1=82; 102-82=20

Comment: Yes our formula needs a new rule. If you encounter a 1 you do the count for that digit (rest to the power of 9) but then are finished.

Comment: @user577395 If you do program this you should probably explain its derivation as well.

Comment: 214: 1*9*9 + 1*9 = 90. Subtract from 215 gives 125

Comment: 2141: 1*9*9*9 + 1*9*9 = 810 (9* last value). Subtract from 2142 gives 1332

Comment: You can code Simone's formula too to see if the results are consistent. We can verify though. The sum to 10^n of numbers not containing a 1 is always 9^n. (each of n digits with value 0 to 9). So for 214 there are 81 such numbers in 0-99, then none until 199 then 9 more (200 and 202-209). 90 as stated therefore subtract from 215 to see how many do contain a 1 (because 0 to 214 is 215 numbers).

Comment: And so. If i find a 1 i break all future operations (in any case) and subtract from n+1 this number?

Comment: Thanks. Thank you very much. I understand this problem. It's such a nice feeling

Comment: I have written some code for it now but haven't tested it yet. I would hope by now you would also have written code.

Comment: How to compile your code?.. My IDE Code::Blocks. C++ console application.

Comment: int main(int argc, char* argv[]) each number in argv is one you want to solve for or write main to read from console if argc is 0 in which case you can also redirect input to a file containing numbers.

Comment: i added int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int input;
    std::cin>>input;
    std::cout<<countNumsContainingOne(input);
    return 0;
}
but for input==30 result==3...

Comment: it is not true from 20 to 99 from 200 to, from 200 to 999

Comment: Help me please... I can't find a mistake in CashCow's code... may be i'm very silly but i want to pass this problem...

Comment: I wrote my code but i want to understand where is mistake in your code. My code http://pastebin.com/Pmh27NSk

Comment: And also it is not homework in fact. It is a problem from site... I ask CahsCow to answer here =(

Comment: I ask CashCow to answer here... please.

Comment: Yes, I see the issue, we should count not including the current number. So f(3) should be 2 and f(30) should be 18. f(single digit) = 0 for 0, 1 for 1, N-1 for any other digit.

Comment: Yes, just upgraded it. My functions count numbers that do not contain a 1 that is strictly less than "input". Then you add one if your number had a 1 to count for N itself. Note that 0 itself counts as a number that does not have a 1. Thus f(1) = 1. This is necessary for the formula to work.

Comment: no hasOneDog =) hasOneDig. But it is not compile \test.cpp||In function 'unsigned int countNumsContainingOne(unsigned int)':|
\test.cpp|51|error: conversion from 'unsigned int' to non-scalar type 'res' requested|

Comment: @user577395 I upvoted CashCow's answer because I think it's brilliant, but I wonder if it wouldn't be better for you to start with something that you can code and understand easily, as it appears that you are not very well versed in programming (for now).

Comment: I have fixed it with the small errors and appear to be getting the correct results from my tests too.

Answer (score 2):

For each number, do this:  create outer loop for all the numbers from 1 to n.

You can `printf()` it to a string buffer (`char[10]` for example), then check the same string buffer if contains '1' with simple `while` loop.

I'll leave the implementation to you :)

Comment: I do not understand how to do it :(

Comment: It's not about efficiency, but about doing the homework.  He will be able to format decimal numbers, iterate through the char array, learn that string is zero terminated, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Since it's tagged homework, I won't give you the C++ code since you should do *some* of the work :-)

You can break it down into two problems, the first one being how to tell if a given number contains a one. This has an elegant recursive solution:

```
def containsOne (n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n % 10 == 1:
        return 1
    return containsOne (n / 10)
```

This will return `0` for any number zero or less and return `1` if it contains a `1`. It does this by recursively checking the least significant digit for a `1`. If it is, it returns `1` otherwise it divides the number by 10 (integer division like `472` becoming `47`) and continues.

Then you have a simple iterative function for counting:

```
def countOfOneNumbersOneTo(n):
    count = 0
    for i = 1 to n:
        count = count + containsOne(i)
    return count
```

That's about the simplest code that'll do the trick.

---

You can see it in action in the following Python code (which is about as close to pseudo-code as a language gets):

```
import sys

def containsOne (n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n % 10 == 1:
        return 1
    return containsOne (n / 10)

def countOfOneNumbersOneTo(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        count = count + containsOne(i)
    return count

print countOfOneNumbersOneTo (int (sys.argv[1]))
```

and transcript:

```
$ python qq.py -10
0

$ python qq.py 0
0

$ python qq.py 1
1

$ python qq.py 9
1

$ python qq.py 10
2

$ python qq.py 29
12

$ python qq.py 100
20
```

---

A C version follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int containsOne (int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n % 10 == 1)
        return 1;
    return containsOne (n / 10);
}

static int countOfOneNumbersOneTo (int n) {
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        count = count + containsOne(i);
    return count;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("%d\n", countOfOneNumbersOneTo (atoi (argv[1])));
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you want raw speed, one option is to pre-calculate all values and write the results to a file. The initial process will be a little slow but, once you have the values written to a fixed-length-record file, the lookup is a simple, relatively fast, `seek/read` operation.

For the number 10<sup>9</sup>, this takes a little over 8 minutes to do on my old clunker laptop and you need to remember that you don't need to do this for every number since, once you've established that `100` has 20 results, you just have to check `101` and add 1 (since `101` has a 1) to the 20. Similarly, knowing that `1999999` has 1468559 results, check `2000000` and add 0 (since it has no 1's).

I've actually used this trick before with a file containing millions and millions of primes. Turning this into a bitmask in a file, I have an `isPrime()` method that blows most any calculating variant out of the water :-)

Comment: It is not homework in fact. It is a problem from site... My code for this problem http://pastebin.com/Pmh27NSk

Comment: @user577395: But you _tagged_ it homework! In any case, it shouldn't be too hard to translate that into C or C++.

Comment: But your code very slow... n can reach 10^9 and time limit is 2 sec

Comment: CashCow's algo is ex. but i can't find a mistake in his implementation. His algo is below

Comment: There was no time limit requirement in the question, nor any indication of an upper limit. So, yes, if you need a faster solution, concentrate on a formulaic solution rather than an iterative one.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's obviously your fault for the question being tagged homework ;) A good answer anyhow.

Comment: pre-calculate is not interesting! =)

Comment: @user577395, since you just seem to keep adding conditions that weren't in the original question, you have zero chance of getting further help on this question. I suggest in future, you pre-specify the conditions so as to not waste anyone's time. Best of luck with your question.

Comment: I added restrictions. It is realy my mistake

Comment: Your solution is O(N) whereas mine is O(log N)

Comment: solution in this post is O(N*logN) isn't it?